# iOS-style formatting callout using Rangy

Tags: javascript, dom, positioning, rangy, callout

I'm looking at Rangy (http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) and it seems it has a bunch of DOM utilities but I don't understand them without examples. So I'm turning to SO with my ideas and hopefully you guys can show me how this can be done:

[image]

What I need to do with Rangy is use it to find the position and dimensions of the selection. I want to get the frame or Rect of the selection, whether relative to the document or parent element. Then I can position my callout accordingly.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the demo that comes with Rangy already illustrates what you want. specifically http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/position.html inside `showSelectionPosition` function

Considering the fact that selection may be spread across multiple elements, it'd be best to use the coordinates of either `startSelEl` or `endSelEl` to anchor your callout to the beginning or end of a selection.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, that demo works but is based on an unfinished and likely abandoned module (fixing the problem it attempts to fix for all possible scenarios and browsers is just too hard and I don't want to support it). However, for most situations, it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is an embryonic, unreleased Rangy module I wrote for getting pixel coordinates of a selection or range. Unfortunately the difficulty of getting this working properly in all browsers and all situations has put me off completing it and I have essentially abandoned it. However, if you add a bit more detail about what you're trying to do I may be able to suggest something.